# Waterfall join conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables similar to:

**Table 1** --unique ID's

```
ID     Date
1      3/8/2017
2      3/8/2017
3      3/8/2017
```

**Table 2**

```
ID     Date          SourceID
1      3/8/2017      1
1      3/8/2017      2
1      3/8/2017      3
2      3/8/2017      2
3      3/8/2017      1
3      3/8/2017      3
```

And I want to write a query that has a result like:

**Result**

```
ID     SourceID
1      2
2      2
3      1
```

Where the source ID ordering should be 2, 1, 3

I have:

```
select Table1.ID
    , COALESCE(Join1.SourceID, Join2.SourceID, Join3.SourceID) as SourceID
from Table1
left outer join Table2 Join1
    on Table1.date = Join1.date
        and Table1.ID = Join1.ID
        and Join1.SourceID = 2
left outer join Table2 Join2
    on Table1.date = Join2.date
        and Table1.ID = Join2.ID
        and Join2.SourceID = 1
        and Join1.SourceID is null
left outer join Table2 Join3
    on Table1.date = Join3.date
        and Table1.ID = Join3.ID
        and Join3.SourceID = 3
        and Join1.SourceID is null
        and Join2.SourceID is null
```

But this currently just keeps the records where `sourceid = 2` and does not add in the other sourceid's.

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if you need any clarification. Using SQL-Server. I only need a few and fixed amount of sources so I am avoiding using a cursor.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here? I don't understand the rules here.

Comment: Since the dates are all the same they don't matter here. Either have some different dates, or remove them.

Comment: Add id 4 to table1 only, and perhaps id 5 to table 2 (if possible).

Comment: This is a subset of larger code but this snippet should be to just take my preferred sourceID in order (2,1,3) and populate that value in my result table. As you can see the first table does not have sourceID's but it does have a unique list of ID's from all sources. I just want to re-map it back to my preferred source.

Comment: @jarlh, the second table does have more dates... I just didnt put in my example

Comment: Which means the dates makes no sense here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  I would do it using `outer apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.sourceId
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id = t1.id and t2.date = t1.date
      order by (case t2.sourceid when 2 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 3 then 3 end)
     ) t2;
```

Note:  For readability, you can simplify the `order by` to:

```
order by charindex(cast(t2.sourceId as varchar(255)), '2,1,3')
```

If you are uncomfortable with `outer apply`, you can do the same thing with a single `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.sourceId
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, date
                                order by (case t2.sourceid when 2 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 3 then 3 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and t2.date = t1.date and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The Single join actually performs much better as I wrote both.